# Problems identifying images in pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, torchvision, dataloader

I am really new at deep learning and I am studying how to properly run neural networks using `pytorch`. Currently I am trying to read a dataset of images using the following code:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torchvision import transforms, utils

transformations = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(255),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])
train_set = datasets.ImageFolder('faces/train', transform = transformations)
test_set = datasets.ImageFolder('faces/test', transform = transformations)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=60, shuffle = True) 
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=60, shuffle = True)
```

once done that, I am trying to read the images to start running the neural networks on the images, first by separating the imgs from the labels using:

```
img, labels = next(iter(train_loader))
```

And then I received the following message:

```
UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BufferedReader name='faces/train/karyadi/karyadi_straight_angry_open.pgm'>
```

The structure of the folders on my working directory where I have stored the images is as follows:

1. faces:

   - Train: 10 folders, each one with around 90 images in pgm format.
   - Test: 1o folders, each one with around 90 images in pgm format.

does anyone know what the problem might be?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of `PIL` do you currently have?

Comment: @Ivan sorry to ask this, what is PIL?

Comment: PIL is the Python imaging library, it's used by torchvision. Could you import it (`import PIL`) and try to load an image with `PIL.Image.open('<path_to_img>')`?

Comment: I receive the same error I posted above. Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure these are valid images?

Comment: Yes. I can open them on my laptop. I just checked my `PIL` version. It is 7.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658539/plt-imreadimg-raises-pil-unidentifiedimageerror) was very useful. The gist of it is that `PIL` has problems importing images of certain sizes (I do not have all the details about this). At the end I use `cv2` to import the pgm images one by one and then convert them into 32-bit ndarrays to export them in jpeg format. Here is my code for one image:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('faces/train/karyadi/karyadi_straight_angry_open.pgm')
img = np.full(img.shape, img, dtype=np.float32)
cv2.imwrite('img.jpeg', img)
```