# Split multi-page tiff image using python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a function that enables me to split the multi-page tiff

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

im = Image.open("Sample.tiff")

for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(im)):
    page.save("Page%d.png" % i)
```

The code is working well for some tiff images but not for all of them. Here's a sample of the tiff that doesn't work with code
It raises an error like that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 6, in <module>
    page.save("Page%d.png" % i)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2130, in save
    self._ensure_mutable()
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 619, in _ensure_mutable
    self._copy()
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 612, in _copy
    self.load()
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1088, in load
    return self._load_libtiff()
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1192, in _load_libtiff
    raise OSError(err)
OSError: -9
```

tiff sample: https://www.mediafire.com/view/9l3iyke0s7t2col/Sample.tiff/file

Comment: [`tifffile`](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) also fails on this one saying `ValueError: cannot decompress ccittfax4`. This is a compression "used for 1-bit fax images sent over ISDN lines". Not sure if that's related to PILs problem with the file, but maybe it's a clue.

Comment: @jeronimo Is there a way to detect if the tiff is valid or not?

Comment: I guess I'd simply `try .. except` the OSError. Technically it is valid, just not readable with that library. You should also be able to read out the compression mode of the tiff and give a more verbose error message to the user in this case, if that's what you wanna do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you help me with that please as I am a beginner? I took about two hours and couldn't solve that point

Comment: I'd like to help but the privacy specifications of that site are ridiculous and I cannot download your file.

Comment: How can I upload the file for you?

Comment: Try this link https://anonfiles.com/Z61cb2Pcx3/Sample_tiff

Comment: That's a DMG file which I don't plan to run either.

Comment: What DMG file? Do you mean the downloaded file is different or what!

Comment: Here's a goof drive link ot two tiff images one is valid and the other is invalid https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TNslo5DOQB2tiOV7BKfsp7WRZj1wdUK0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: My suggestion would be to process it in Python Wand, which can save out your pages as separate images. Python Wand is based upon Imagemagick, which is on most Linux distributions and available for Windows and Mac.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you post an answer with an example of code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which one of your two files works and which one doesn't! I checked both files with:

```
tiffinfo IMAGE1.TIF > 1.txt
tiffinfo IMAGE2.TIF > 2.txt
```

then I diffed the two text files with:

```
opendiff [12].txt
```

[image]

The main difference is the *compression* - both of which are potentially problematic for some software. One is **CCITT Group4** and the other is JPEG-compressed.

If you don't have `tiffinfo` (part of the TIFF library package), you can alternatively use:

```
exiftool IMAGE.TIF
```

or **ImageMagick**:

```
magick identify -verbose IMAGE.TIF
```

---

I suggest you check your PIL installation with the following as you need `lib tiff` installed for handling compressed images:

```
python -m PIL

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Pillow 9.0.1
Python 3.10.0 (v3.10.0:b494f5935c, Oct  4 2021, 14:59:19) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL
Binary modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok, compiled for 9.0.1
--- TKINTER support ok, loaded 8.6
--- FREETYPE2 support ok, loaded 2.11.1
--- LITTLECMS2 support ok, loaded 2.13
--- WEBP support ok, loaded 1.2.2
--- WEBP Transparency support ok
--- WEBPMUX support ok
--- WEBP Animation support ok
--- JPEG support ok, compiled for libjpeg-turbo 2.1.2
--- OPENJPEG (JPEG2000) support ok, loaded 2.4.0
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok, loaded 1.2.11
--- LIBTIFF support ok, loaded 4.2.0
*** RAQM (Bidirectional Text) support not installed
*** LIBIMAGEQUANT (Quantization method) support not installed
--- XCB (X protocol) support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BLP
Extensions: .blp
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BMP image/bmp
Extensions: .bmp
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BUFR
Extensions: .bufr
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
CUR
Extensions: .cur
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DCX
Extensions: .dcx
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DDS
Extensions: .dds
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DIB image/bmp
Extensions: .dib
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
EPS application/postscript
Extensions: .eps, .ps
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FITS
Extensions: .fit, .fits
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FLI
Extensions: .flc, .fli
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FTEX
Extensions: .ftc, .ftu
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GBR
Extensions: .gbr
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GIF image/gif
Extensions: .gif
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GRIB
Extensions: .grib
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
HDF5
Extensions: .h5, .hdf
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ICNS image/icns
Extensions: .icns
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ICO image/x-icon
Extensions: .ico
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IM
Extensions: .im
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IMT
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IPTC
Extensions: .iim
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
JPEG image/jpeg
Extensions: .jfif, .jpe, .jpeg, .jpg
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
JPEG2000 image/jp2
Extensions: .j2c, .j2k, .jp2, .jpc, .jpf, .jpx
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MCIDAS
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MPEG video/mpeg
Extensions: .mpeg, .mpg
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MSP
Extensions: .msp
Features: open, save, decode
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PCD
Extensions: .pcd
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PCX image/x-pcx
Extensions: .pcx
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIXAR
Extensions: .pxr
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PNG image/png
Extensions: .apng, .png
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PPM image/x-portable-anymap
Extensions: .pbm, .pgm, .pnm, .ppm
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PSD image/vnd.adobe.photoshop
Extensions: .psd
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SGI image/sgi
Extensions: .bw, .rgb, .rgba, .sgi
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SPIDER
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SUN
Extensions: .ras
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TGA image/x-tga
Extensions: .icb, .tga, .vda, .vst
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TIFF image/tiff
Extensions: .tif, .tiff
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
WEBP image/webp
Extensions: .webp
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
WMF
Extensions: .emf, .wmf
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XBM image/xbm
Extensions: .xbm
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XPM image/xpm
Extensions: .xpm
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XVTHUMB
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you can't get PIL working, you might consider Christoph's [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/).

---

Note that `exiftool` can tell you the compression like this:

```
exiftool -s -s -s  -compression Sample1.tiff
T6/Group 4 Fax
```

Or, same with Python:

```
import exiftool

# If  "exiftool" is not on your PATH, add the full path inside parentheses on next line
with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
     c = et.execute(b"-compression", b"Sample1.tiff")
```

---

You can also get the TIFF compression type with the Python [magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/) module:

```
import magic

print(magic.from_file('a.tif'))
```

**Sample Output**

```
'TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=16, height=20, bps=0, compression=LZW, PhotometricIntepretation=RGB, orientation=upper-left, width=20'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sample1.tiff is invalid while Sample2.tiff is valid. My question now is how can I detect if it is valid or invalid using the python package PIL or any other library?. I check PIL version and I noticed TIFF is supported

Comment: I haven't tried, but I guess you get an error, or `None` returned when you open an invalid one, or maybe an exception is thrown that you could catch. Or maybe the dimensions are (0,0) or somesuch if you try to load an invalid one. Or maybe you can configure `Envision` not to produce incompatible ones? Or maybe you can install `libtiff` to deal with them properly.

Comment: Is it possible to check only the compression information for the tiff file?

Comment: I have added that to the bottom of my answer - please have another look.

Comment: Imagemagick uses libtiff to process tiff files. libtiff cannot handle older format JPG compressed tiffs. I do not know if that is your issue or not.

Comment: I am using windows and as for the last part I got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exiftool'`. I tried `pip install exiftool` but it seems not to work. I searched and found that `pip install PyExifTool`, it works now. But how can I add it to the path?

Comment: I have searched and installed the exiftool then add it to the variables PATH in windows. But when trying the code I got `FileNotFoundError: "exiftool.exe" is not found, on path or as absolute path`

Comment: You have to start a new command prompt for any PATH change to take effect. Or you can put the full path to `exiftool.exe` in the parentheses in the code where I annotated it.

Comment: I missed a step as I had to move it to `C:\Windows` folder. Now I can check the version using this line in cmd `exiftool -ver` (Now it is supposed to work). But when trying the code again, I got a different error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`

Comment: The command line is working well `exiftool -s -s -s  -compression Sample1.tiff`, but as for the python code, it doesn't work. Is it possible to modify the code to work as a command line (I mean to use the command propmt line in the python code)?

Comment: I could use VBA to execute the exiftool on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71535852/hide-popup-window-when-exectuing-commad-line but how can I do the same as for python?

Comment: You can use `subprocess()` to execute the commandline that works well https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I added a further way to get the TIFF compression using `python-magic` at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to change the image compression type?

Comment: @YasserKhalil **ImageMagick** can probably convert a multi-page TIFF to PNGs just in the Terminal with `magick INPUT.TIF OUTPUT-%d.PNG`

Comment: @YasserKhalil Else you could try `tiffsplit` and/or `tiffcp` which are provided when you install `libtiff`

Comment: This line is a great start `magick INPUT.TIF OUTPUT-%d.PNG`. Can you guide me how to run command line in python so as to be able to do the split process from dos in python?

Comment: @YasserKhalil You can use `subprocess` - see my earlier comment above.

Comment: Thank you very much for guiding me. Now I searched and could do it with this line `subprocess.call(['magick', '279010101375.tiff', 'OUTPUT-%d.png'])`. How can I apply such a line to multiple images inside a folder? And how can I use variables in such a line instead of the filename and the output filename?

Comment: @YasserKhalil You can try `magick mogrify -format PNG *.tif` to do all TIFFs in the directory.

Comment: Amazing. I have searched before your comment and found mogrify command but seems not work as it seems should have magick before it. How can I determine the input directory from this line and the output directoy as I need the results to be in a separate folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243322/discussion-between-mark-setchell-and-yasserkhalil).