# Hide popup window when exectuing commad line

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that enables me to loop through TIFF images in specific folder to determine the compression type and the code is working fine except for one point, which is the following:
with each file, a popup window appearing and after a second disappears. How can I get rid of the popup window of the command prompt console?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wshShell As Object, sFolder As String, strFile As String, sCommand As String, sOutput As String, r As Long
    sFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestFolder\"
    strFile = Dir(sFolder & "*tiff*")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        sCommand = "exiftool -s -s -s  -compression " & sFolder & strFile
        Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        sOutput = wshShell.Exec(sCommand).StdOut.ReadAll
        r = r + 1
        Cells(r, 1).Value = Replace(strFile, ".tiff", "")
        Cells(r, 2).Value = Application.Trim(Split(sOutput, vbCrLf)(0))
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

The question is related to another topic on the following link
[Split multi-page tiff image using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71511742/)

Comment: Well in standard Wscript you add `, 0` to the end of your Run line so I assume it's the same with what you have. Try `sOutput = wshShell.Exec(sCommand).StdOut.ReadAll , 0` The parameter is for windowstyle and 0 is for hidden (1 for normal). There is also a second parameter for _waitonreturn_ which is `True/False` to force the VBA to wait for the execution to finish before continuing the code. Depending on what you're doing it may be beneficial or simply just slow your code down.

Comment: I put 0 at the end of the line you refer to but it is not valid for vba in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it with a workaround of exporting the result of the command line to a temp text file

```
Sub Test()
    Dim fso As Object, wshShell As Object, sFolder As String, sFile As String, sCommand As String, sOutFile As String, sOutput As String, r As Long
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\IDs\"
    sFile = Dir(sFolder & "*tiff*")
    sOutFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Out.txt"
    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        sCommand = "cmd /c exiftool -s -s -s  -compression " & sFolder & sFile & " > " & sOutFile & ""
        Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        wshShell.Run sCommand, 0, True
        With fso
            sOutput = .OpenTextFile(sOutFile).ReadAll()
            .DeleteFile sOutFile
        End With
        r = r + 1
        Cells(r, 1).Value = Replace(sFile, ".tiff", "")
        Cells(r, 2).Value = Application.Trim(Split(sOutput, vbCrLf)(0))
        sFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```